# Number of rectangles generated by $n$ points in the plane

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-geometry

This sounds like a problem that would have been *definitely* studied by some paper, and to defend myself I have searched using various tools for some time to no avail.

What is the configuration of $n$ points in the plane that creates the maximum number of rectangles having them as vertexes, and what is the (asymptotic) maximum number?

To be clear, a rotated rectangle, such as $(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)$ is also treated as a rectangle.
The points do not have be in the lattice.
Any references to the literature, or related results will be appreciated!

Edit - I do not expect a closed form formula for all $n$, even a result on the lines of $O(n^2)$ will be very useful.

Comment: If $n$ is a perfect square, $n=p^2$ the best configuration is probably to define $A_p=\{(a,b), a \in \mathbb{N}, b \in \mathbb{N},  1\le a \le p, 1\le b\le p \} $ ; an interesting problem is to count how many rectangles we have with this configuration $A$ ; if $n$ is not a perfect square, it is more complex  ; Before searching the best configuration, it is certainly useful to build a formula to count the number of rectangles for such set of points : $B_{p,q}=\{(a,b), a \in \mathbb{N}, b \in \mathbb{N},  1\le a \le p, 1\le b\le q \} $

Comment: I believe so too in the square case - but even then I do not know what would be the "Formal proof", perhaps it is only something achievable by a computer, but I am not knowledgable in this area enough.

Comment: Do you consider also rectangles rotated by an an angle $\ne 90°$ like $(1,0),(0,2),(5,3),(4,5)$ ?

Comment: I understood that all rectangles and only rectangles are accepted. $(1,0)(0,2)(5,3)(4,5)$ is not a rectangle.

Comment: Sorry I meant  $(1,0)(0,2)(5,2)(4,4)$

Comment: yes, rectangles rotated by any angles are accepted. that's one of the things that make this hard

Comment: This question in MO asks about the number of rectangles in a square lattice grid: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352095/number-of-rectangles-in-an-n-by-n-grid-of-points.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step ...

With $n= p \times q$ points in $B_{p,q}=\{(a,b), a \in \mathbb{N}, b \in \mathbb{N},  1\le a \le p, 1\le b\le q \}$, we can search how many rectangles we can build. We search for an **asymptotic** estimation.  (asymptotic is important !)

Question 1 : how many rectangles with sides parallel to the grid : easy, $p \times (p-1) \times q \times (q-1) /4$

Question 2 : how many rectangles parallel to this specific direction (2,1)  (means that 1 side is parallel to the vector AB, with A(0,0) and B(2,1) ?
Probably we need to decompose this question into more detailed questions.
For a rectangle not parallel to the grid, I define the 1st corner as : the corner with minimum y.

So this question 2 can be detailed :

- how many rectangles with one side parallel to vector (2,1), and first corner in the 1st row of the grid ?
- how many rectangles with one side parallel to vector (2,1), and first corner in the row $y_0$ of the grid ?
- Estimate the sum of all values, for $y_0=1$ to $q-1$

Question 3 : generalisation, same question with any direction $(a,b)$ with $gcd(a,b)=1$  ; I filter with this restriction $gcd(a,b)=1$, to avoid duplicates.

Question 4 : When we have a general formula to estimate the number of rectangles with a specific direction, we need to sum all values, for all valid directions.

Each question is challenging, but step by step, it seems to be reachable.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A289832

Answer (score 0):

I have been notified by one of my friends this paper: https://pure.tue.nl/ws/files/4288742/369233.pdf .
It gives a lower bound of $\Omega(n^2)$ and an upper bound of $O(n^{2.5})$.
However there may be better results and I will keep the question open.